# How to use the output we see of expression when this expression is inside Dynamic

Tags: dynamic

Consider this example:

```
Manipulate[status = Dynamic[If[a < b, Yes, No]], {a, 2}, {b, 5}]
```

The output of this calculation is

```
(*Yes*)
```

when I call status again I get `Yes` as expected.

No when I want to used the output of status in further calculation I failed. I tried to do the following:

```
status === Yes
```

the results is `False`

The full form of status is not what is seen in the output.

My question is, how to use the output of expression no matter what the definition of that expression is.

(Note: `status[[1]]` does not help because the level of the output is unpredictable)

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at `Setting`. Moreover, first argument of `Manipulate` is effectively wrapped in `Dynamic` so the one in your code is only making problems with it's head and gives nothing.

Answer (score 1):

```
(status /. Dynamic -> Identity) === Yes
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you  want the value of `status` outside of the `Manipulate` to be updated whenever it changes inside the `Manipulate, just drop the explicit`Dynamic`.

```
 Manipulate[status = If[a < b, Yes, No], {a, 2}, {b, 5}]
 Dynamic[status === Yes]
```

The `Manipulate` will still work as it did before the change, and the second expression will track the changed to `status` made inside the 1st.